# Dynamic table as data source in SSAS

Tags: sql, ssas

I want to use dynamic table as my data source in SSAS to create my Time Series model. But only views and static tables from my database are shown in the data source wizard.Is there any method to access available dynamic tables in the database as data source?

Because I need to create around 20-25 models by changing the parameter of dynamic table. If I can't access the dynamic table I have to create 20-25 static tables or views which is very inefficient.